# SharePoint framework with classic view

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, modern-pages

**Can we use SharePoint framework web-part with classic view** (I.e. with Our custom Master pages and Page Layouts)?

SharePoint framework is only to use it with our Modern view.? Or to use it with both classic view(like add-in) as well as modern view.?

Thank you.!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SPFx webparts in modern pages and classic pages both.

Once uploaded in the app catalog and installed in the site collection, you can use it on the your classic pages which have custom page layouts and master page.

It will appear in the webpart gallery under the "Under development" section and then you add it like you add a normal webpart.

[image]

Reference - [Creating/Provisioning modern pages and SPFx webparts](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/03/provisioning-modern-pages-and-spfx-web-parts.html)

Waldek's blog [SPFx on classic pages - correctly reference images in SPFx](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/correctly-reference-images-sharepoint-framework-solutions/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation to the question. I have one more doubt, about "How to access the property pane on custom Classsic view (Custom master pages) "?? As  i am only able to see the property pane in modern view.

Comment: You can click on the edit webpart. It will open up webpart properties, there you will have an option to configure. Have added a screenshot. You just have to click on configure and it will open the property pane

Comment: Is there some prerequisite that modern experience needs to be turned on for the site for this to work in classic pages? Or some other dependencies? I have modern experience disabled for whole tenant. Will SPfx work for this case?

Comment: No prerequisites. SPFx webparts will work regardless of tenant settings. However, if you are planning to use SPFx extensions, then you need modern experience.